# How do I tell whether my phone is roaming?

Tags: mobile-network, roaming

How do I tell whether my phone is roaming, preferably on the lock screen?

Comment: Or any way to show that whether the phone is in roaming since that's my purpose.

Comment: @beeshyams Sorry for my messed up question. Also my question belongs to forums, i shouldn't have posted here. My mother commutes to a neighboring state, i asked the question for her. Will ask her to notice whether "R" appearing. Thanks.

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks, "R" does appear :)

Comment: I turned off Data Roaming in Settings/Connections/Mobile networks, but the "R" is still there. Why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's [intention](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179531/see-current-location-without-internet-as-a-user?noredirect=1#comment230744_179531)
 of asking was to know how to identify the mobile is in roaming

It is indicated by **R** (indicating Roaming) , next to the signal strength icon, which was indeed the case

[image]

Comment: I turned off Data Roaming in Settings/Connections/Mobile networks, but the "R" is still there. Why??

Comment: No idea! Very strange

Comment: @user610620 Data Roaming only affects mobile data usage when it's roaming. However, it doesn't turn off the roaming itself.

Comment: So how is it really turned off?